# How can I switch between multiple sets of network configurations on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I do consulting and carry my Windows XP laptop from employer to employer.  In some of the places I go to, they have unique network settings, so sometimes I have to sit there and change my network settings (e.g. type in DNS servers, IP values, etc...).

Of course, when I get to another employer, I have to reset the settings back to the original.

Is there a way to save these various settings and change them as needed in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [netsh.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468) along with a few batch-files, and you're good to go!  Not only is it *free*, it's **included with Windows**, and you don't need anything constantly running in the background.  Just have a few configuration files set as different files, and run a different one to switch your network settings!

For example, if I wanted to change my "Local Area Connection" (the name shown in Network Connections), then I would copy and paste the following into Notepad, and save it as "something.bat":

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
```

This would set my network connector named "Local Area Connection" to have a static IP of 192.168.0.100, with netmask 255.255.255.0, and a default gateway of 192.168.0.1.

For some advanced examples, check out [this article](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm), or the [documentation from Windows XP Professional](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true).

And yes, you can set the DNS via this tool as well:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.200
```

Comment: +1 great answer using free-as-in-already-paid-for software. :)

Comment: The "this article" link got outdated.

Comment: @TomWijsman interesting, it works when I copy and paste the following into my browser: `http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm` but it doesn't work when I click the link...  I think they might be preventing hot-linking.

Comment: @Breakthrough: Works for me by just clicking now, odd. Perhaps depends on browser? :/

Answer (score 2):

**For Free:**

[Avanquest Connection Manager](http://www.avanquest.com/USA/software/avanquest-connection-manager-107347)

**For Pay:**

I've seen good reviews for both [NetSwitcher](http://www.netswitcher.com/) and [Mobile Net Switch](http://www.mobilenetswitch.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this article from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283676). It tells you how to use the **Alternate Configuration feature** for multiple network connectivity in Windows XP. You can have multiple metwork configurations at the same time; you only have to switch between them. Easy and free!

Comment: That doesn't help if he needs a static IP at work as well.  That only applies if one network has DHCP and the other doesn't.

Comment: I know my wife used such a configuration, that's why I recommended it. I admit, considering your responses, you have a larger degree of knowledge on the subject :)

Comment: That's a good point.  At least one of my configs involves a static setup.

Comment: Yes, alex, this would be perfect for the OP depending on his needs.  Most people can set it statically at home and use DHCP at work, or vice-versa.