# How to change IP address using script on Windows?

Tags: windows-7

I need fixed IP in three wireless networks I log in frequently.

It is a pain to set those IP and gateway everytime I change networks.

I am willing to write a script to change my IP and gateway between those 3 fixed IPs and a choice to make it get IP automatically (when I´m in another network).

A plus feature to my script would be if it could discover the wireless network I am logged in and decide the IP automatically.

Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I switch between multiple sets of network configurations on Windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/36470/how-can-i-switch-between-multiple-sets-of-network-configurations-on-windows-xp)

Answer (score 15):

`ipconfig /renew` to get a new IP address or default gateway
The `NETSH` command does this. check [this](http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/how-change-address-from-command-prompt-t25858.html).

See this example for setting DNS address manually via `netsh` command:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.200
```

configure your NIC to dynamically obtain its DNS settings (`* Obtain DNS server address automatically`):

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

and to set the `* Obtain an IP address automatically` setting:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

More info: read this [Configure TCP/IP from the Command Prompt](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd.htm) and [How to change IP address from command prompt](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-13513-how-to-change-ip-address-from-command-prompt).

This is assuming 3 things.

1) The network adapter you're trying to change the IP for is "local area connection". It could also be "local area connection 2" or "wireless network connection". Look in your control panel for the correct name.

2) The IP you want to set is 192.168.0.101, change this to whatever IP to want to use.

3) The default gateway and dns are the same IP. If you are using some kind of router they usually are. Change this to match your network config found with the command `ipconfig /all`

---

Here is example of batch file that I have created for your problem solutions: just change the command after the `con1:` type labels

How to create batch file:
paste this code in notepad and save it as `"test.bat"`

**Note:** Change your connection names `"local area connection"` to your `"wireless connection"` name

```
@ECHO off
cls
:start
ECHO.
ECHO 1. Change Connection1 Static IP 
ECHO 2. Change Connection2 Static IP 
ECHO 3. Change Connection3 Static IP 
ECHO 4. Obtain an IP address automatically
ECHO 5. Exit
set choice=
set /p choice=Type the number to print text.
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto con1
if '%choice%'=='2' goto con2
if '%choice%'=='3' goto con3
if '%choice%'=='4' goto autosearch
if '%choice%'=='5' goto end
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
ECHO.
goto start
:con1
ECHO Connecting Connection 1
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
goto end

:con2
ECHO Connecting Connection 2
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection1" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
goto end

:con3
ECHO Connecting Connection 3
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection2" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
goto end

:autosearch
ECHO obtaining auto IP
ipconfig /renew "Local Area Connection"
goto end

:bye
ECHO BYE
goto end

:end
```

Hope this help you..
for more reference check this [Set Your IP Address Via Batch File](http://samanathon.com/set-your-ip-address-via-batch-file/)

Comment: I get `Adapter is not enabled for DHCP` when trying `ipconfig /renew "Wireless Network Connection"`

Comment: I used this `netsh interface ip set address "Wireless Network Connection" dhcp` and this for auto dns
`netsh interface ip set dns "Wireless Network Connection" dhcp`

Comment: To set dns manualy, I had to use `netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Wireless Network Connection" address=8.8.8.8 index=1` from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620173/how-can-i-set-change-dns-using-the-command-prompt-at-windows-8/18626717

Answer (score 4):

You can make a .bat script file that contains the configuration commands based on "netsh" command, for [example](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-13513-how-to-change-ip-address-from-command-prompt):

> This changes the IP address and Default Gateway:
>
> "netsh int ip set address "local area connection" static {192.168.0.101} 255.255.255.0
> {192.168.0.254} 1"
>
> This changes DNS:
>
> "netsh int ip set dns "local area connection" static {192.168.0.254} primary"

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old thread but still it can be useful to many like me.

As per the op asked for WiFi, I have created a batch script for Wi-Fi. It will fetch current Wi-Fi connected and based on that set Static IP or DHCP.

Here is the script -

```
@echo off
Ping www.google.com -n 1 -w 1000
cls
if errorlevel 1 (
    if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)

    :start
        for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%n in ('netsh wlan show interface name="Wi-Fi" ^| findstr ^/R "\<SSID"') do set "Network=%%n"
        set "Network=%Network:~1%"

        IF "%Network%"=="Home" goto DHCP 
        ELSE IF "%Network%"=="OfficeWifi1" goto Static 
        ELSE IF "%Network%"=="AnotherOffice2" goto Static2 
        ELSE IF "%Network%"=="OpenWifi" goto DHCP
        ELSE goto DHCP  

    goto end
    :Static
        set IP=192.168.1.118
        set Sub_Mask=255.255.255.0
        set D_Gate=192.168.4.4
        set DNS=192.168.4.1
        set DNS2=192.168.4.2

        netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static %IP% %Sub_Mask% %D_Gate% 1
        netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" static %DNS%
        netsh interface ip add dns name="Wi-Fi" addr=%DNS2% index=2
        netsh int ip show config
    goto end
    :Static2
        set IP=192.168.2.201
        set Sub_Mask=255.255.255.0
        set D_Gate=192.168.4.4
        set DNS=192.168.4.1
        set DNS2=192.168.4.2

        netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static %IP% %Sub_Mask% %D_Gate% 1
        netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" static %DNS%
        netsh interface ip add dns name="Wi-Fi" addr=%DNS2% index=2
        netsh int ip show config
    goto end
    :DHCP
        netsh int ip set address name = "Wi-Fi" source = dhcp
        netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" source="dhcp"
    goto end
    :end
        msg * "WLAN wise IP is set up"
)
```

You should save this a batch file and run that batch file as %% in for command will not work in command prompt.

**TIP:**
You can also add this in Task Scheduler with Trigger as below and Action with above batch path

```
Trigger : On an event
Log: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational
Source: NetworkProfile
Event ID: 10000
```

***Update***

In Windows 10 & 11, you can set the IP configuration as well as DHCP / Static settings for each Saved WiFi network also.

Answer (score 2):

Run this on CMD as admin:

to static:

```
netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
```

back to dhcp:

```
netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

`"Local Area Connection"` can be different in your case

Answer (score 0):

in this cmd how to set dns
netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).