# What is the shortest path to set IP4/IP6 settings in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking

What is the shortest known path to change IP4 settings for network connection in Windows 7?  Are there any hotkeys or key combinations that will take you directly to Network Connections without having to go through Network and Sharing Center?

Sorry if this is a duplicate as I was not able to find one before posting.

Comment: You can use some batch files to do this easily; see [my answer here](http://superuser.com/questions/36470/how-can-i-switch-between-multiple-sets-of-network-configurations-on-windows-xp/36476#36476).

Comment: Yeah, scripts are nice as long the network connection remains the same name of `Local Area Connection` and you have access to the machine. I am looking for something that can be used over the phone, not to discredit your answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Start (or hit the <kbd>Win</kbd> key), and start typing "View network connections". Eventually you should be able to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will bring you straight to the control panel listing all your network connections.

As an aside, that search bar will bring you most anywhere, and I use it primarily when instructing people how to do things on their computer when giving tech support over the phone.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be with a script.  You can modify the powershell script below to your liking.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
function Set-IPAddress 
{
        param(  [string]$NIC=$(read-host "Enter the NIC to be set (example: "Local Area Connection")"),
                [string]$IP = $(read-host "Enter an IP Address (ie 192.168.0.5)"),
                [string]$NM = $(read-host "Enter the subnet mask (ie 255.255.255.0)"),
                [string]$GW = $(read-host "Enter the Gateway (ie 192.168.0.1)"),
                [string]$DNS1 = $(read-host "Enter the first DNS Server (ie 8.8.8.8)"),
                [string]$DNS2 = $(read-host "Enter the second DNS Server (ie 8.8.4.4)"),
                [string]$registerDNS = "TRUE"
             )
        $DNS = $DNS1
        if($DNS2){$DNS ="$DNS1,$DNS2"}
        $index = (gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter | where {$_.netconnectionid -eq $NIC}).InterfaceIndex
        $NetInterface = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.InterfaceIndex -eq $index}
        $NetInterface.EnableStatic($IP, $SN)
        $NetInterface.SetGateways($GW)
        $NetInterface.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNS)
        $NetInterface.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($registerDns)

}
```